# Notepad++ and NppExe not showing me an output

Tags: c, notepad++, mingw-w64

I want to learn C. I would like to get my notepad++ to compile and run my .c files. I have done what is needed to be done. I am using MinGW and have added the plugin. I added this prompt:

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"

gcc -Wall -Werror "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3

NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

but whenever I go to compile and run, a command prompt appears and takes all the input. But when the time comes to show me an output command prompt closes out. Also there is no output on the console embedded in the notepad++ either. I then have to use Windows cmd to execute. Can someone please help me. I am a beginner.

for instance, take a look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Note: Program assumes years are in the same century. */

int main(void)

 {

 int month1, day1, year1, month2, day2, year2;
 int first_earlier = 0;

 printf("Enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
 scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month1, &day1, &year1);

 printf("Enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
 scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);

  if (year1 != year2)
      first_earlier = year1 < year2;

  else if (month1 != month2)
      first_earlier = month1 < month2;
  else
     first_earlier = day1 < day2;

   if (first_earlier)
  printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month1, day1, year1, month2, day2, year2);

   else
   printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n",month2, day2, year2, month1, day1, year1);

   getchar();
  return 0;

  }
```

when pressing F6, the command prompt appears, it asks dates and when pressing enter after entering the second date prompt closes without showing me an output anywhere.

Comment: If you are learning C, don't compile your C code with C++!

Comment: You need to put a call to `getchar()` at the end of `main`. That will keep the window open until you press a key. Also, change `g++` to `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @user3386109 Printing a message such as`"Press Enter to continue..."` before calling `getchar()` is even better.

Comment: @machine_1 Yeah, ok. If you want to be nice to the user, I guess that's fine :)

Comment: Hello good folks. Thanks for everything. So i did this: npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"

gcc -Wall -Werror "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3

NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)

Comment: and added getchar(); at the end just like mr. Pablo mentioned. Yet it still closes. Sorry.

Comment: my best advice to you is to forget notepad++ and go with a proper IDE designed for programming development.

Comment: *sigh* i really wanted to use this. I was getting hang of it.

Comment: I made an update of my answer addressing your problem. In the feature, please don't ask the same question twice. If you have some problem with an answer, leave a comment. The person who answered will notice that. If you however have a **new** question, then you can of course create a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `g++` is the C++ compiler. If you have C code, then you have to
use `gcc` to compile C code.

I don't really understand what you mean by *a command prompt appears and takes
all the input*, but judging from the behaviour that the console closes
immediately, then this is because the console closes right after the program
exits.

When making a double-click on an (console) executable, a terminal is spawned and
it executes your program (not the command line). Normal behaviour of terminals is that when the
executed program exists, the terminal closes. This also would happen when
launching the program through your IDE.

As you can see, if you open a terminal and execute it from there, the terminal
stays open, because the command line is still active<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to launch a program via double-click or IDE, then you have to make
sure that your program doesn't exit right away. An easy way to do this is by
making the user wait for an input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");

    puts("Press Enter to continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here the `getchar` would wait for user input and it would exit after the user hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This is a workaround for launching console programs via
double-click and IDEs. However I think this is bad practice, the correct way
would be to start a terminal yourself and execute your program yourself.

Many terminals have the option that they don't close immediately when the
running program ends. For that you should be able to check the settings of the
terminal. Sometimes IDEs have also a checkbox in the settings that you have to
check so that the terminal doesn't close right away.

**edit**

The reason why `getchar` at the end does not wait is because of the previous
`scanf`.

When you enter something in the command line, a newline (`'\n'`) is also added
to the input stream.

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);
```

If the format is correct, `scanf` will consume all input but leave behind the
newline in the input buffer. The last `getchar()` will consume the newline that
is already in the buffer, and because of that it doesn't wait for further user
input.

You have to clear your input buffer. Add this function before the `main`:

```
void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

The call it after the `scanf` calls:

```
printf("Enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month1, &day1, &year1);
clear_stdin();

printf("Enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);
clear_stdin();
```

Now that the input buffer is cleared, the last `getchar` will wait for more user
input and you program will block until you press ENTER.

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>Note that a terminal (console) is **not** the same as the command
line. The terminal is the program that displays the text and allow users to
type with the keyboard. A command line is just a program that allows you to
enter commands and start programs. In Windows the command line is `cmd.exe`
called command line, it is mostly found in `C:\Windows\System32`.

The default settings are that when you open a terminal without telling which
command to execute, it will automatically open a command line, in Windows would
be `cmd.exe` by default.

Comment: Yes sir, you are right, it closes immediately. I added getchar(); but it closes again/ I have made changes to the npp exec too. npp_save cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" gcc -Wall -Werror "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3 NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)

Comment: Please help. I don't know how to reply to you. First timer in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. This is overly complicated. I might just use some other software. Hurdle after hurdle. But its ok.

Comment: @Ulta this is exactly how to reply to an user, by leaving a comment in the comment section. The creator of the answer will see a notification when someone leaves a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment I know you still don't have enough rep. points to comment everywhere, but you can always comment on answers of your own questions.

Comment: Thank you! :) I am gonna use Putty and notepad++. or WinSCp? What do you recommend @Pablo?

Comment: @Ulta they are 3 unrelated programs. But sure, open a putty session on a remote server (or virtual machine), compile and execute it there. And use winscp to move the files. I think it's much more easier if you open a terminal in windows, enter `cd path\to\your\build\directory` and execute the binary from there, don't you think? But if it works well for you with these 3 programs, go ahead.